# Need to flip background color 360deg by X axis in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to make a flip animation of one block of color in my HTML page. It has to flip 360 deg. Here is my HTML and CSS codes. I am new at this, so I don't know where to even start. If someone could try to do that and explain how it works.

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    max-width:1680px;
    height:100vh;
}

.zydra{
    background-color: #00BFFF;
    width:30%;
    height:50%;
    float: left;
}

.zalia{
    background-color: #228B22;
    width: 70%;
    height: 10%;
    float: left;
}

.geltona{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    width: 35%;
    height: 10%;
    float: right;
}

.melyna{
    background-color: #000080;
    width: 35%;
    height: 10%;
    float: left;
}


.oranzine{
    background-color: #FFA500;
    width: 70%;
    height: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.ruda{
    background-color: #8B4513;
    width: 15%;
    height: 40%;
    float: left;
}

.raudona{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    width: 35%;
    height: 40%;
    float: left;
}

.balta{
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

.juoda{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (max-height: 1024px){

    body{
        margin:0;
        max-width: 768px;
        max-height: 1024px;
    }

    .zydra{
        background-color: #00BFFF;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        float: left;
    }

    .zalia{
        background-color: #228B22;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10%;
        float: right;
    }

    .melyna{
        background-color: #000080;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10%;
        float: right;
    }

    .geltona{
        display: none;
    }

    .oranzine{
        background-color: #FFA500;
        width: 50%;
        height: 30%;
        float: right;
    }

    .ruda{
        display: none;
    }

    .raudona{
        background-color: #FF0000;
        width: 40%;
        height: 40%;
        float: left;
    }

    .balta{
        background-color: white;
        width: 60%;
        height: 40%;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .juoda{
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>
        Kursinis darbas
        </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" content="initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="zydra"></div>
        <div class="zalia"></div>
        <div class="geltona"></div>
        <div class="melyna"></div>
        <div class="oranzine"></div>
        <div class="ruda"></div>
        <div id="balta" class="balta" onmouseover="pirmaT()" onmouseout="pirmaN()" ><span id="pirma">Tekstas</span></div>
        <div class="raudona"></div>
        <div class="juoda"></div>

        <script>
            function pirmaT(){
                document.getElementById("pirma").style.color = "white";
                document.getElementById("balta").style.backgroundColor = "black";
            }

            function pirmaN(){
                document.getElementById("trecia").style.color = "black";
                document.getElementById("balta").style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you talking about. 1. Do you mean "rotate"? "Flip" doesn't make sense together with "360 degrees". And if you do mean rotate, what is this thing about "background-color" - you don't rotate colors, you rotate containers. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes. So I may have been refering to rotation. I have a div and its background color is the one I need to rotate.

Comment: The background color stays the same? (white) but the div rotates 360 degrees? No need to use javascript, though. Just css will do that nicely on :hover

Comment: This is div: <div class="melyna"></div>

Comment: This is div: <div class="melyna"></div> and it only has this css code and nothing more: .melyna{
    background-color: #000080;
    width: 35%;
    height: 10%;
    float: left;
}

I need to flip it when mouse is over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery](https://jquery.com/) and [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) !

Here is [how to implement animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css#usage) in your html !

Here is how to make only one flip :

```
$.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function (animationName) {
        var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    }
});
```

Replace #yourElement by your tag id name :

```
$('#yourElement').animateCss('flip');


$('#balta').animateCss('flip');
```

And in your html, you can init jquery like that

```
    <script>
        $('#balta').mouseover(function(){
             $('#balta').animateCss('flip');
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: It is great, but a for now at my lectures we are only allowed to use HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - everything in CSS, no JS needed

```css
@keyframes spin { 100% { transform:rotate(360deg); } }

body{
    margin:0;
    max-width:1680px;
    height:100vh;
}

.zydra{
    background-color: #00BFFF;
    width:30%;
    height:50%;
    float: left;
}

.zalia{
    background-color: #228B22;
    width: 70%;
    height: 10%;
    float: left;
}

.geltona{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    width: 35%;
    height: 10%;
    float: right;
}

.melyna{
    background-color: #000080;
    width: 35%;
    height: 10%;
    float: left;
}
  .melyna:hover {
animation:spin 4s linear;    }



.oranzine{
    background-color: #FFA500;
    width: 70%;
    height: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.ruda{
    background-color: #8B4513;
    width: 15%;
    height: 40%;
    float: left;
}

.raudona{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    width: 35%;
    height: 40%;
    float: left;
}

.balta{
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

.juoda{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (max-height: 1024px){

    body{
        margin:0;
        max-width: 768px;
        max-height: 1024px;
    }

    .zydra{
        background-color: #00BFFF;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        float: left;
    }

    .zalia{
        background-color: #228B22;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10%;
        float: right;
    }

    .melyna{
        background-color: #000080;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10%;
        float: right;
    }


    .geltona{
        display: none;
    }

    .oranzine{
       background-color: #FFA500;
        width: 50%;
        height: 30%;
        float: right;
    }

    .ruda{
        display: none;
    }

    .raudona{
        background-color: #FF0000;
        width: 40%;
        height: 40%;
        float: left;
    }

    .balta{
        background-color: white;
        width: 60%;
        height: 40%;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
    }
  .balta:hover span {
    color: white;
    }
  .balta:hover {
    background: black;
    }

    .juoda{
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="zydra"></div>
        <div class="zalia"></div>
        <div class="geltona"></div>
        <div class="melyna"><span>text</span></div>
        <div class="oranzine"></div>
        <div class="ruda"></div>
        <div id="balta" class="balta"><span id="pirma">Tekstas</span></div>
        <div class="raudona"></div>
        <div class="juoda"></div>
    </body>
```